# Uploading CSV and writing to a SQL database using php

Tags: php, sql, fgetcsv

I'm trying to upload a csv and write it to a SQL database.

Here is the code I'm using.

upload.php

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="form">

            <?php

                include "connection.php"; //Connect to Database

                $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE price_upload"; //empty the table of its current records
                mysql_query($deleterecords);

                //Upload File
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
                        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
                        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
                        //readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
                    }

                    //exclude the first row

                    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
                    $firstRow = true;

                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        if($firstRow) { $firstRow = false; }
                        else {
                            $import = "INSERT into price_upload(Buy_Grp, Item_No, Item_Desc, Manufacturer, Department, Barcode, Range ID, Planogram, Start_Price, Trading_Term, Basket, End_Date, Min_Qty, Assorted_Qty, Discount) values ('".$data[0]."',".$data[1].",'".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."',".$data[5].",'".$data[6]."','".$data[7]."','".$data[8]."','".$data[9]."','".$data[10]."','".$data[11]."',".$data[12].",'".$data[13]."','".$data[14]."')";

                            //print $import;
                            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
                        }    
                    }    

                    fclose($handle);

                    print "Import done";

                    //view upload form
                } else {

                    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

                    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

                    print "File name to import:<br />\n";
                    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
                    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>                  </form>";    
                }    

            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I run it, no data gets written to the database.

When I print $import on the screen, I get this.

```
INSERT into price_upload(Buy_Grp, Item_No, Item_Desc, Manufacturer, 
Department, Barcode, Range ID, Planogram, Start_Price, Trading_Term, Basket, 
End_Date, Min_Qty, Assorted_Qty, Discount) values ('11',31/01/17,'9','-
','8.00% Buying',53629,'MORTEIN COIL BURNER 30 CT6','RECKITT BENCKISER','-
','19300700000000','-','-',26.18,'0.00%','107411')INSERT into 
price_upload(Buy_Grp, Item_No, Item_Desc, Manufacturer, Department, Barcode, 
Range ID, Planogram, Start_Price, Trading_Term, Basket, End_Date, Min_Qty, 
Assorted_Qty, Discount) values ('ams',7.35,'1.00%','-','-',1,'-','0.00% 
Buying','53835','COLGATE T/B TEENS DESIGN IT','COLGATE PALMOLIVE PTY 
LTD','Oral Care',9300630000000,'-','url').....
```

The data doesn't seem to be pulling in the correct values or columns.

Not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Make sure order and number of column in CSV and database table are same. First try manually printing them.

Comment: Please add sample CSV data also.